# Derivative of trace of fourth-order matrix product?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I've been able to find all I need in the handy Matrix Cookbook, but today I encountered a form that is not in the book. Could anyone show me what is

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}X}\operatorname{tr}(A^TX^TXAB^TX^TXB)$$

---

MATLAB's symbolic computations told me

```
>> syms X A B;
>> diff(trace(A'*X'*X*A*B'*X'*X*B), X)

ans =

2*A*B*X*conj(A)*conj(B)*conj(X)^2 + 2*A*B*X^2*conj(A)*conj(B)*conj(X)
```

But a quick check shows that I am using MATLAB wrongly,

```
>> syms X A;
>> diff(trace(X*A), X)

ans =

A
```

since the correct answer should be $A^T$.

Comment: I think matlab may use denominator format which means in symbol $\frac{\partial y}{\mathbf X}$ the $\mathbf X$ stays same while numerator would be transposed. In either case $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf X}tr(XA)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf X}tr(AX)=\mathbf A$ or $\mathbf A^T$ depending on the notation chosen, and if the notation is switched the result will switch. Not sure if able to change between numerator/denominator form in matlab.

Comment: @marshalcraft Thanks for your insight! I still think it's my mistake in usages (rather than the convention differences), because regardless of conventions, sizes of $A$ and $B$ may not allow multiplications (see `2*A*B*X...`). Maybe MATLAB is taking `X, A, B` as scalars.

Comment: @marshalcraft Denominator layout would be $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf X}tr(XA)=A^T$ right?

Comment: Yes my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(X)=\operatorname{tr}(A^TX^TXAB^TX^TXB)$. Then the first order approximation of $f(X+H)-f(X)$ (when $H$ is small) is given by
\begin{align}
&\phantom{=}\operatorname{tr}(A^TH^TXAB^TX^TXB)
+\operatorname{tr}(A^TX^TH\color{red}{AB^TX^TXB})\\
&\phantom{+}+\operatorname{tr}(A^TX^TXAB^TH^TXB)
+\operatorname{tr}(A^TX^TXAB^TX^TH\color{red}{B})\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(H^TXAB^TX^TXBA^T)
+\operatorname{tr}(\color{red}{AB^TX^TXB}A^TX^TH)\\
&\phantom{+}+\operatorname{tr}(H^TXBA^TX^TXAB^T)
+\operatorname{tr}(\color{red}{B}A^TX^TXAB^TX^TH)\\
&=2\operatorname{tr}(H^TXAB^TX^TXBA^T)
+2\operatorname{tr}(H^TXBA^TX^TXAB^T),
\end{align}
where we have used the property that $\operatorname{tr}(PQ)=\operatorname{tr}(QP)$ in the first equality and that $\operatorname{tr}(P)=\operatorname{tr}(P^T)$ in the second one. It follows that $\frac{df(X)}{dX}=2(XAB^TX^TXBA^T+XBA^TX^TXAB^T)$. (And of course, if you use a transposed layout for the derivative, you should take the transpose of the above expression as the answer.)

Comment: +1; Thanks a lot for the answer! May I ask two questions: (1) how may I obtain the first-order approximation? Is it similar to what we do in single variable (instead of matrix): expanding $f(X+H)-f(X)$ in full and discarding "second-order terms" (maybe $H^TH$)? (2) for single variable, we can do $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$; what should I do here? Dividing the trace by $H$? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user1551 not sure what you mean by first order approximation bit but +1 on the transposed layout.

Comment: @SibbsGambling (1) Yes, just like the single variable case, i.e., expand $f(X+H)$ and ignore all higher-order terms (and yes, that includes $H^TH$). (2) In the multivariate case, $f$ is differentiable at $X$ iff there exists a linear map $Df(X)$ such that $\lim_{H\to0}\frac{\|f(X+H)-f(X)-Df(X)(H)\|}{\|H\|}=0$ (this is the usual textbook definition), meaning that $f(X+H)-f(H)=Df(X)(H)+o(\|H\|)$ (note: this is little-oh, not big-oh). So, a higher-order term means any expression whose norm is $o(\|H\|)$ and you may throw it away because they are too small when compared to $\|H\|$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you kindly make links to my question (2) clearer? I'm quite new to matrix calculus and still don't get how I can go from $f(X+H)-f(X)\approx 2\operatorname{tr}(H^TXAB^TX^TXBA^T)
+2\operatorname{tr}(H^TXBA^TX^TXAB^T)$ to $\frac{df(X)}{dX}=2(XAB^TX^TXBA^T+XBA^TX^TXAB^T)$. Also, may I ask if you are using the numerator layout? This layout thing is really confusing to a novice like me... Thanks again!

Comment: @SibbsGambling Let $E_{ij}$ denotes the matrix with a 1 at the $(i,j)$-th entry and zeros elsewhere. Now someone takes $\frac{df(X)}{dX}$ to mean $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{ij}})$. That is, its $(i,j)$-th entry is the directional derivative of $f$ along the linear span of $E_{ij}$. If $f(X+H)-f(X)=tr(H^TM)+o(\|H\|)$ for some matrix $M$, then  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{ij}}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(X+hE_{ij})-f(X)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h\cdot tr(E_{ij}^TM)}{h}=m_{ij}.$$ Hence $\frac{df}{dX}=M$.

Comment: Yet some others like to take $\frac{df(X)}{dX}$ to mean $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{ij}})^{\color{red}{T}}$. In this case $\frac{df}{dX}=M^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Using product rule for differential forms, cyclic permutations, and that trace is linear

$$dtr(A^TX^TXAB^TX^TXB)=dtr(BA^TX^TXAB^TX^TX)=tr(d(BA^TX^TXAB^TX^TX))$$

$$=tr(d(BA^TX^T)XAB^TX^TX+BA^TX^Td(XAB^TX^TX))$$

$$=tr(d(BA^TX^T)XAB^TX^TX+BA^TX^T(d(XAB^T)X^TX+XAB^Td(X^TX)))$$

$$=tr(d(BA^TX^T)XAB^TX^TX+BA^TX^T(d(XAB^T)X^TX+XAB^T(d(X^T)X+X^Td(X)))$$

$$=tr(d(BA^TX^T)XAB^TX^TX+BA^TX^Td(XAB^T)X^TX+BA^TX^TXAB^T(d(X^T)X+X^Td(X)))$$

$$=tr(d(BA^TX^T)XAB^TX^TX+BA^TX^Td(XAB^T)X^TX+BA^TX^TXAB^Td(X^T)X+BA^TX^TXAB^TX^Td(X))$$

$$=tr(BA^Td(X^T)XAB^TX^TX)+tr(BA^TX^Td(X)AB^TX^TX)+tr(BA^TX^TXAB^Td(X^T)X)+tr(BA^TX^TXAB^TX^Td(X))$$

$$=tr((BA^Td(X^T)XAB^TX^TX)^T)+tr(BA^TX^Td(X)AB^TX^TX)+tr((BA^TX^TXAB^Td(X^T)X)^T)+tr(BA^TX^TXAB^TX^Td(X))$$

$$=tr(X^TXBA^TX^T(dX)AB^T)+tr(BA^TX^Td(X)AB^TX^TX)+tr(X^T(dX)BA^TX^TXAB^T)+tr(BA^TX^TXAB^TX^Td(X))$$

$$=tr(AB^TX^TXBA^TX^T(dX))+tr(AB^TX^TXBA^TX^Td(X))+tr(BA^TX^TXAB^TX^T(dX))+tr(BA^TX^TXAB^TX^Td(X))$$

$$=tr(AB^TX^TXBA^TX^T(dX)+AB^TX^TXBA^TX^T(dX)+BA^TX^TXAB^TX^T(dX)+BA^TX^TXAB^TX^Td(X))$$

$$=tr((AB^TX^TXBA^TX^T+AB^TX^TXBA^TX^T+BA^TX^TXAB^TX^T+BA^TX^TXAB^TX^T)d(X))$$

$$=tr((2AB^TX^TXBA^TX^T+2BA^TX^TXAB^TX^T)d(X))$$

this shows that $\frac{\partial tr(A^TX^TXAB^TX^TXB)}{\partial X}= 2AB^TX^TXBA^TX^T+2BA^TX^TXAB^TX^T$

Comment: To me it does seem deliberately unclear as I've expressed, if you had asked for the derivative in terms of $X$ and $A$ I think that is what  you want. Additionally if you had only referred to the derivative of a linear map instead of a matrix; that would not be with respect to a basis and require a more general result.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, let
$$\eqalign{
 C &= AB^T \cr
 Y &= X^TX = Y^T \cr
}$$
Use the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and these new variables to write the function, differential, and gradient as
$$\eqalign{
 f &= C:YCY \cr\cr
df &= C:dY\,CY + C:YC\,dY \cr
   &= CYC^T:dY + C^TYC:dY \cr
   &= (CYC^T+C^TYC):dY \cr
   &= (CYC^T+C^TYC):2\,{\rm sym}(X^TdX) \cr
   &= 2\,{\rm sym}(CYC^T+C^TYC):X^TdX \cr
   &= 2\,X\,(CYC^T+C^TYC):dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= 2\,X\,(CYC^T+C^TYC) \cr
   &= 2\,X\,(AB^TX^TXBA^T+BA^TX^TXAB^T) \cr
}$$